# How to organize things/books in a packed shelf?

Tags: home, organization

Current messy situation of my shelf:

[image: shelf]

The problem is, I don't have much place elsewhere, so all the things you see need to stay in in this shelf.

The shelf is big in depth, so two rows of books are possible at every stage. However, that is somewhat impractical because it's complicated to get to the books at the back or to even see what's there if you are searching for something or just want to get inspired about what to look into.

Comment: Do you consider solution of downloading them electronically on your pen-drive and throw them away?:) It'll save a lot of space.

Comment: put the books standing up in the back of each row (however many rows you need).. then in the front of each row don't put more books. Put the gadgets and cords and what not in front of the rows of books. This way you should still see the titles/books that are in the back row and can access them, and the smaller items will be in the front where they're visible.

Comment: @bluet: That's a nice recommendation, thanks. However, it will not work if there are too many books in total (and I think that is the case for me).

Comment: I think it would be best if you acquaint yourself with the retro game 'Tetris' and once you have mastered that - return to this shelf and use what you have learned.

Comment: You could think about putting the smaller stuff (cables etc.) into (possibly labeled) boxes and stack the boxes into the shelf.

Comment: I see you have one shelf unused. What's under the bottom shelf? It looks as if there's space unused under the four visible full shelves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting books in and cables inside any box will help you gain space also you can make small stickers like index of the box or any item you put in it.

**Some reasons to make cartoon boxes for your goods.**

- Keep your books or goods away from dust and dirt
- You can write notes and indexes about what inside
- You can move any place easily instead of trying to move all books one by one
- While you have a chance to cut or bend they can fit any place
- They can be recycled ( Be green)
- You can paint it in any color :D

For mode idea you can make a little walk at IKEA :D I had bought some boxes from them to clean my tidy desktop at home. Today I am not willing to pay while I can find for free cause people throw them away.

[image: I Uses boxes cause they are everything]

[image: Another example]

Answer (score 4):

The big problem seems to be the assorted wires, devices, and similar, that you can't stack very easily. I would recommend putting them in a box or boxes, so you can stack other things on top of them, and it's easier to put them somewhere else (under the bed, say), without too much hassle, and without makes things untidy.

I would also recommend putting any loose papers in a ring-binder if they can fit vertically on a shelf, or a box file, which can stack, or go vertically. Smaller manuals could also go into box files for protection, and to keep related ones together.

Basically, if everything is stackable and easy to move, that should help you use the space more efficiently, and make it easier to rearrange. Also, make sure stacks are level. I don't like the look of the book underneath the black box on top of the shelves, it could make the box unstable if you put anything else on top of the box.

Those are the main things I think you could do.